# Why won't console.log show my whole javascript multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I make an array like this in Javascript:

```
    var tabInfos = [];
    tabInfos[1] = [];
    tabInfos[1]['label'] = 'one';
    tabInfos[1]['id'] = '111';
    tabInfos[2] = [];
    tabInfos[2]['label'] = 'two';
    tabInfos[2]['id'] = '222';
```

How can I get console.log(tabInfos) to show the first value as well (e.g. 1, 2):

[image]

Comment: Why are you using an array for key-value pairs? That's what `Object`s are for.

Comment: try it with tabInfos[1].label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see the first item as undefined is because it is.
JS Arrays start at 0 and you start yours at 1.

Have a look at the recommended way of getting what you seem to want - an array of objects:

```js
var tabInfos = [{
  "label": "zero",
  "id": "000"
}, {
  "label": "one",
  "id": "111"
}, {
  "label": "two",
  "id": "222"
}];

console.log(tabInfos);
// or if you must
console.log(JSON.stringify(tabInfos));
```

Comment: window.console && console.log(JSON.stringify(tabInfos)) works nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using objects, not arrays for your internal items.  They are not array-like.

```
var tabInfos = [];
tabInfos[1] = {};
tabInfos[1]['label'] = 'one';
tabInfos[1]['id'] = '111';
tabInfos[2] = {};
tabInfos[2]['label'] = 'two';
tabInfos[2]['id'] = '222';
```

Comment: +1, but you're still making the same mistake of indexing from 1

Comment: You're right.  Responding in too much of a hurry.  But @mplungjan's answer is better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this as follows:

```
var i = 0;

JSON.stringify(tabInfos, null, 2).split(/\n/).forEach(function(line) {
  window.console && console.log(
    (/\s{2}\S/.test(line)) ? i++ + line : line
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually by your screenshot the console *DOES* show the values of tabInfos[1] and tabInfos[2] first value, it is shown *inline* right after the minus sign [-] and because there are no values in them nothing appears on the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabInfos = [];
    tabInfos[1] = {};
    tabInfos[1].label = 'one';
    tabInfos[1].id = '111';
    tabInfos[2] = {};
    tabInfos[2].label = 'two';
    tabInfos[2].id = '222';
```

but making tabInfos an object instead of array is recommended(then you can make associative array also means you can have named properties).

Answer (score -1):

Are you worried about the first undefined value? JavaScript arrays are 0 indexed. If you set the first value from 1, then the 0th position automatically becomes undefined.

Comment: This should be a comment.